# How can i calculate the volume of a fitting surface in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have three properties of a surface (Easting, Northing and depth) in each E & N.

I want to fit a surface to these points and then calculate the volume of this fitted surface in each ***dx***, ***dy*** and ***dz*** and then compare it with some other data.

Can you help me do that ?

Comment: The _volume_ of a surface implies that it is bounded on all sides. Can one assume that the "depth" is one surface, and `depth = 0` is the other surface? Does `depth` ever change sign? Do we assume that the "edges" of the volume (limits of x and y) are "straight drops" - going from Z=depth to Z=0? Finally, are the values of z tabulated on a regular grid of x and y, or is the grid irregular? Sorry to ask so many questions - it's necessary to be able to write a working solution.

Comment: So, Let me explain you. i have a region that has some coordinates( i presented them: Easting=x, Northing=y and depth=z). this information is about a hydrocarbon reservoir so it is clear that sign of all z is - and we dont have a sharp difference in near x and y coordinates.so we can fit a good surface to them. for better imagination you can presence an anticline that lies in earth.Now i want to make some grids that can assign them some properties so i imagine that this anticline is in a cube.

Comment: i have to denote the top and bottom of this anticline, conversely i have some information about the coordinate of top and bottom of the anticline, so i try to fit a surface that can be consider as a top of the anticline and then calculate the volume of this surface in each boundary grids to decide that is it reservoir or not

Comment: All of this information should go into the question. Just sayin'.

Comment: whats your mean? icant get you

Comment: I think you are saying you want to be able to tell whether a point lies within the reservoir or not - you don't need to know the volume? Please clarify by editing your question with all the information. I realize English is probably not your first language but it is hard to understand what you are asking for!

Answer (score 0):

To calculate volume of your surface compared to the flat plane at depth 0 just do

```
volume_ref = sum(sum(data)) * dx * dy * dz;
```

To get the volume compared to another surface (e.g. anticline) calculate the volume of the anticline with respect to the same reference (depth 0) and then subtract.